# Firebase isn't transferring data to node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So at the moment I have a node server set up to connect to my Android app. I can get the custom auth token, username and email fine. But when I add in a height and weight for the users registration, that goes through fine. It saves in the firebase database but when I try to get the data back it doesn't come back.

Node.js server

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((id)=>{
        if (id == socket.id) {
          var token = {
            authToken:customToken,
            email:data.email,
            userName:snapshot.val().userName,
            height:data.height,
            weight:data.weight
          }
```

Android code. What happens here is I'll get the token, email and userName perfectly fine. But height and weight doesn't. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
JSONObject getData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("token");
String token = (String) getData.get("authToken");
String email = (String) getData.get("email");
String userName = (String) getData.get("userName");
String height = (String) getData.get("height");
String weight = (String) getData.get("weight");

userDetails.add(token);
userDetails.add(userName);
userDetails.add(email);
userDetails.add(height);
userDetails.add(weight);

return userDetails;
```

Comment: Can you give more context on what's going on here? How's firebase related? Does your backend actually send a height and weight? What do you do with `userDetails` when it's returned?

Comment: Yes it sends the height and weight when the user registers, the userDetails get into a .next() in a string array and gets added to the sharedpreferences.

Comment: I'd double check the two places where you might have a problem: in the network layer (i.e. if you see the network response, does it have those two fields?) and the deserialization layer (i.e. where the network response gets converted into `jsonObject`. Are the fields there? Do they have an empty value? null?

Comment: So I printed out the token in a console.log on the server and I get null in the height and weight fields. But everything returns perfectly fine, I'm not sure why they return null.

Comment: Well, then the problem seems to be even before you get to Android, so there's nothing to do there. Going back to the server: where is that `data` object coming from? Seems like that's the culprit in your case

Comment: data object is coming from here `  socket.on('userInfo',(data)=>{`

Comment: Ok I figured out what was happening, I wasn't actually getting the values from the database I was getting them from the authentication, but once I added `snapshot.val().height` I was able to get the values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I did it similar to getting the username so instead of data.height/data.weight
I used `snapshot.val().height, snapshot.val().weight` and that worked. Thanks to guys that helped me